# Is there a better way to set the onClickListner for the whole layout?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout` and I want to respond to the user's clicks on the `LinearLayout`. So I write:

```
<LinearLayout
    Some Attributes
    onClick="layoutOnClick">

</LinearLayout>
```

However, if I click on the views on the `LinerLayout`, the `layoutOnClick` method doesn't get called. That means I need to add the same onClick attribute to every view in the `LinearLayout`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `clickable` attribute to your `LinearLayout`, and set it to `true`.

**Edit:**

If this doesn't work, the answer will be more complicated. You could create a custom `ViewGroup` that extends `LinearLayout`, and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()`. Return `true` in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, and add the logic for your click to `onTouchEvent()`.

[These Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept) docs go into more detail.

Answer (score 0):

While you are designing a view inside a layout, the layout will completely occupied with the views[buttons/edittext etc]. So you cannot click the layout accurately. Better to add listeners for each views or a single view. Else if you are able to click the layout accurately then obviously it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely occupied"? What if the child view only takes a part of the layout?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah of course you can add an event listener to a single LinearLayout element.

Give an id attribute to the Linear Layout,

```
             <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/llSendMoney"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
```

Refer it in the code like this,

```
             private LinearLayout llSendMoney;
             this.llSendMoney = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSendMoney);
             this.llSendMoney.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and in the onclick event

```
           @Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v.getId()== R.id.llSendMoney) {

        //do whatever you want here in the onclick event
        }

    }
```

I mean yeah if you cannot tap the view more accurately then you might consider a design change of your UX. Or either you maybe trying to address an issue that has a more clear solution like using a fragment inside your linearlayout. By the way I am pretty curious to see your Layout file to get a more clear idea of what you are after.

Comment: This is not the solution of the problem. He has no problems setting the onClick listener, but rather that this listener doesn't activate when he presses the child views of the layout.

Comment: @Dchaser88 My layout has a few text views

Comment: cool. Then why don't you make you child view unclickable like this,
textview.setOnClickListener(null);
    view.setOnLongClickListener(null);
    textview.setLongClickable(false); and make the outer linearlayout clickable, this way it will work yeah?